# css is late applied in FireFox, IE but not in Chrome

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

When page is loaded in FireFox and IE the text is plain
and then css is applied. Around 400 ms latency.
This is not happening in Chrome.

Using Bootstrap v3.3.7

Aside main-menu.

How can I fix this effect?

Comment: How you adding css file by JS script or by <link /> tag?

Comment: Do you have a url we can look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have render blocking elements in your HTML that are being loaded before the CSS is applied.

You should move all your JS to the BOTTOM of your page and make sure your CSS links are in your head.

If that does not work, take it one step further and pull out the CSS you need to render those items directly from your file and put it directly in your head. This is actually a known practice to make a page "appear" to load faster.

More info here:

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/render-blocking-css

Comment: Your solution worked.
Another issue I'm facing with a Button is visible even It has 
aria-hidden="true".
I hide it also with a JS but there is a delay hiding, so is visible for while.

Comment: "aria" tags are for screen readers - not for hiding DOM elements. You will want to add some CSS and use display: none; to hide the button. Since you're using bootstrap you can just add the "hide" class to the button